# Firewalld forwarding whole subnet

Tags: firewalld

I have a network that looks like this:

MyPC:
eth0 10.208.65.80/18

Machine A (Linux, Running a WebServer)
eth0 10.208.65.101/18
eth1 192.168.2.1/24

firwalld zones:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
block
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

dmz
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

drop
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

external
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

home
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

internal
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

m100 (active)
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1 lo
  sources: 
  services: mdns ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
    rule family="ipv4" protocol value="icmp" accept

public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

trusted
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

work
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Machine B (Running a WebServer)
eth0: 192.168.2.2/24

i configured the following things:
a route on MyPC: `ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 10.208.65.101`
enabled ipforwarding on Machine A: `echo 1 >> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
fire wall configuration:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=m100 --add-masquerade
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=m100 --add-forward
#allow forwarding to host 192.168.2.2
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=m100 --add-forward-port=port=1-65535:proto=tcp:toport=1-65535:toaddr=192.168.2.2
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=m100 --add-forward-port=port=1-65535:proto=udp:toport=1-65535:toaddr=192.168.2.2
#allow forwarding of icmp(ping):
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=m100 --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" protocol value="icmp" accept'
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

With this i can open a browser on MyPC and navigate to 192.168.2.2 and get the page served by Machine B.

**I would like modify the -add-forward-port rules so that every thing to 192.168.2.0/24 is forwarded. Not just a single host.**

I tried to remove the toaddr= but when i do that and navigate to 192.168.2.2 i get the page served from Machine A.

Comment: Are you specifically trying to set up NAT, or do you want regular non-NAT routing?

Comment: If i remember correctly NAT will hide one network from the other? If thats right its non-NAT. (Both sub nets should see each other.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `--add-forward-port`. That sets up a DNAT rule (what people call "port forwarding") – not actually forwarding per se, but translation.

If your interfaces are in the same zone, `--add-forward` should be enough to enable [intra-zone forwarding](https://firewalld.org/2020/04/intra-zone-forwarding).

If they were in different zones, you would probably have had to add a custom rule (the examples I've found all use iptables syntax; although I use nftables I don't know how to do it with nftables-based firewalld).

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -o eno1 -i eno2 -j ACCEPT
```

> If i remember correctly NAT will hide one network from the other?

Not exactly. People usually associate this with NAT, but in reality that happens because of 1) missing routes and 2) firewall. The presence of NAT just "papers over" the issue of missing routes such that things appear to work in one direction but usually not in the other.

That being said, you *definitely shouldn't* have NAT in the middle of your network if you can avoid it.

Comment: ok i now just executed this commands:sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=m100 --add-masquerade
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=m100 --add-forward sudo firewall-cmd --reload and now i have the behaviour when i navigate to 192.168.2.2 i get the page served on Machine A.

Comment: a ok masquerade needs to be disabled. And you need to white list the Services. Now it works thanks :)